# WordPress authenticate admin in plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I verify a user `is_admin()` in a wordpress plugin file that looks similar to this:

```
// Load WP core
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require( '../../../wp-load.php' );

if (is_admin()) {
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    echo base64_decode($pdf_data);
}
```

Basically, a user will go to a php file within the plugin and if they are logged in as Admin, they get to see the pdf data. If they are not logged in, they don't see anything.

Comment: Don't directly load a .php file located in the plugins folder - everything needs to go through the wordpress api. https://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus

Answer (score 0):

I think would look a lot like this:

```
// Load WP core
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require( '../../../wp-load.php' );

function so_48351789(){
  global $user;
  $the_ID = $user->ID;
  if (is_admin($the_ID)) {
      header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
      echo base64_decode($pdf_data);
  }
}
add_action( 'send_headers', 'so_48351789' );
```

You'd also only want to fire that on one-page, see: [Example from the WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen)